# Linux Power management API

Tags: linux, api, power-management

Is there a power management API in Linux? If so what is it?

I want to be able to program my C application to prevent suspend/hibernate while it's running.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your application running as root?

Comment: Probably it is `ACPI` and `udevd` related.

Comment: have you seen Linux going into low power states while your application is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) provides some basic power management functionality within the `org.freedesktop.PowerManagement` bus.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suspend the linux system in C program, you could write "mem" or "disk" to the attribute file "/sys/power/state". Writing "mem" means suspend to the ram, and writing "disk" means suspend to the disk.